# How to show method parameter tooltip in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

VS2010:

In VB I can place the cursor inside an existing method's parameter brackets and type a 'space', which will bring up the tooltip with description of the parameter I'm at. This is not the case in C#. I have to delete the whole brackets including the parameters, and retype the left bracket, for this tooltip to show. Is there some shortcut or setting to change this behavior? I tried hitting ctrl, shift, alt, but it has no effect.

Comment: Pointer to the original answer : [**ctrl+k, p**][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15434084/1042934

Comment: @OgnyanDimitrov Ctrl+Shift+Space

Answer (score 341, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> will do what you want.

You might want to check out a [poster of key bindings](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=e5f902a8-5bb5-4cc6-907e-472809749973&displaylang=en).

Comment: AFAIK, this doesn't bring up parameter info where the caret is within the parentheses for the parameters.

Comment: Looking at the chart, CTRL+Shift+Space looks like the one.

Comment: Cool, I even printed it off myself :P

Comment: Thanks! That works. So then I assume it can not be changed to "automatic" behavior?   Btw, here is similar link for VS2010: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=92ced922-d505-457a-8c9c-84036160639f&displaylang=en

Comment: Also make sure you don't have Resharper installed, as it overrides this shortcut. If you do, you can remove the override in the `Tools > Options > Keyboard` menu: search for commands with "CodeSmart".

Comment: <del>What's this called? I would like to remap it.</del> It seems to be `Edit.ParameterInfo`

Comment: I wanted the same thing for VS2015, in 2012 it would pop up after the first bracket, in my install of 2015 it didn't, but the ctrl+shift+space worked. Thanks

Comment: by default, Ctrl+Shift+Space corresponds to `Edit.ParameterInfo`.

Answer (score 41):

It's <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-I</kbd> for VS2015. In case people from the future are wondering wandering.

Answer (score 19):

I don't understand what you mean exactly. But I use this coding for method parameters tooltip.

```
/// <summary>
/// Do work function
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">This is user's Id.</param>
/// <param name="name">This is user's Name.</param>
/// <param name="surname">This is user's surname. </param>
private void DoWork(int id, string name, string surname)
{ 
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I believe he already has the XML documentation. The problem is making the tooltip appear for an existing method call.

Answer (score 9):

**Visual Studio 2019 with VsVim extension**

Works both in `NORMAL` and `INSERT` modes, for C# and C++ with:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

Just make sure to place the caret right after the first parenthesis:

**C#**

```
"Value".Contains(|   <-- caret
```

**C++**

```
glClearColor(|  <-- caret
```

Comment: How do you iterate through the parameters?

Answer (score 6):

```
Ctrl + K, Ctrl + P
```

Worked for me where `Ctrl + Shift + Space` didn't. Perhaps due to Resharper?

Comment: Unfortunately in 2022 it does not work. IIRC it worked in 2019 Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable way to know it (due to plugins etc) is to look it up in settings.

1. Open settings window: `Tools` -> `Options`
2. Go to `Environment` -> `Keyboard`
3. (optional) Filter commands via `Show commands containing:` field (e.g. type in "param" there)
4. In **VS** 2017, 2019 and 2022 the name is "**Edit.ParameterInfo**" (default binding is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>)
5. In **ReSharper** 2021 the name is **ReSharper.ReShareper_ParameterInfoShow**

Also here is [a list of all shortcuts in MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio), which has command names along with description. I find it easier to search commands there rather then inside in-app settings.