# visual studio parameter listing intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Intellisense typically pops up when I open the '(' on a function call showing the data types of the parameters matched, allowing you to hit up or down to see all possibilities of overloaded function calls.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to force this to happen if I move cursor focus outside the function call and want to see it again?

Comment: I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33210565/193634

Answer (score 22, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> shows the parameter information..

Obtained from [Whats the default intellisense shortcut in vs2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145371/whats-the-default-intellisense-shortcut-in-vs2008) reposted by Rahul

Answer (score 16):

Go to tools->options->keyboard then find Edit.ParameterInfo and assign whatever shortcut you want to it. Default is ctrl+k, p

Comment: Ctrl+K, P is more correct answer since Ctrl+Shift+Space sometimes will do other things besides give you parameter information.

Comment: This should be the most fitting answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this shortcuts

```
crtl + space
```

and

```
crtl + j
```

See this post as well

[Visual Studio keyboard shortcut to display intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640544/visual-studio-keyboard-shortcut-to-display-intellisense)

[What's the default intellisense shortcut in vs2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145371/whats-the-default-intellisense-shortcut-in-vs2008)