# How to get parameter hints/completion in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, autocomplete, intellisense

I usually use Eclipse for coding, which has a pretty nice parameters completion feature: when you are calling a method, just after you typed <kbd>(</kbd>, it will show you the list of parameters, and highlight where you are as you type:

[image: Example of parameters completion in Eclipse]

How can I get similar help in Visual Studio 2012?

I know that <kbd>Ctrl + K, Ctrl + I</kbd> shows some info about what your cursor currently highlights, but it doesn't work if you already have started typing something. If I type `MyMethod(arg1,` and then hit the shortcut (or any other, such as <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + Space</kbd>), I don't get anything useful.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. This brings up the argument list for a method your cursor is currently in.

Example:

[image: typing]

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> with the cursor after `"a",` results in:

[image: ctrlshiftspace]

You can check this is properly assigned in the keyboard settings, as `Edit.ParameterInfo`:

[image: assigned]

Comment: It's supposed to, but it doesn't work. Where can I check that this was not reassigned?

Comment: YOu can look in the Keyboard settings in Visual Studio. Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard. Check that the default template is being used.

Comment: I just did, and even hit the `Reset` button: still nothing. Could the feature be disabled somehow?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm starting to despair... Thanks a lot for your help by the way, nice screenshots!

Comment: Is the intellisense functionality working at all? If you type an opening bracket do you get the list?

Comment: No, not event. I can get completion on variables and methods though, but I never get it for parameters.

Comment: Well, I'll be damned: I restarted VS2012, and lo and behold!, it works. Sorry for wasting your time, thanks again for your help.

Comment: Does VS show parameters after each comma, or am I dreaming this up?

Comment: @nagates It should. I had the same problem that Wookai was having - Parameter Info Intellisense was not showing up despite me not messing with the default settings/keybindings. I also had to restart visual studio and then it worked fine.

Comment: Is there support for this feature on mac? I have been unable to find it if so.

Answer (score 6):

For my case, neither <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> nor <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> work.. eventually I nailed it down to this settings:

[image: Visual Studio Text Editor Intellisense]

Now whenever I typed <kbd>(</kbd>, intellisense will automatically pop up!.. nice!

As it turned out, this is caused by Resharper..., the Resharper uninstall doesn't correctly restore the original Visual Studio settings.

Comment: This is such an underrated answer, this is exactly what should be turned on by default.

Answer (score 1):

Since Visual Studio 2019 you can get inline parameter name hints as well. It can be activated under Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced. Check `Display inline parameter name hints`.

[image]

Parameters will then show up like this in UI:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

visual studio 2019

you can add a button to tool bar:

view>toolbar> text editor.

Then:

view>toolbar>Customize:

Select  commands tab.

Select Toolbar radio button.

On toolbar dropdown select Text Editor.

[command location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2klM.jpg)
Press "add new command.

Select Edit [wait to populate].

Select parameter Info.
[command image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55Rdt.jpg).

Hope this helps.