# Visual Studio keyboard shortcut to get parameter info/definition

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts

How to get parameter info/definition using keyboard keys. I can get first parameter info detail (cmdtext) by default when using `CTRL+SHIFT+SPACE`

[image]

here ***cmdText**: The text of the query.*
I need to get second parameter info i.e. **connection** - ? using keys.

Which keys to be used to navigate between multiple parameters and see parameter definition.

I am using Visual Studio 2015, 2017.

Comment: Did you put your cursor (insertion point) on `connection` first?

Comment: It's CTRL + SHIFT + SPACEBAR. See these answers for more:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582134/how-to-get-parameter-hints-completion-in-visual-studio#:~:text=Ctrl%20%2B%20Shift%20%2B%20Space.%20This%20brings%20up,a%20method%20your%20cursor%20is%20currently%20in.%20Example%3A

Answer (score 0):

Just press comma and you'll get the next definition.

[image]

Comment: not this way. you are editing. without editing, I have to navigate between arguments and see info/definition of existing code.

Comment: It shows the info for the parameter under the cursor.  If you don't want to edit, then just use Right Arrow to get your cursor over to the next parameter.  (Or Ctrl+Right Arrow)

Comment: I don't see the big deal in writing a few commas to see the info you need, then deleting them. Anyhow, I'm not aware of such functionality in VS. Intellisense will give you the information about the parameter when you need it (i.e. when you type the argument), not before. It also doesn't seem to be mentioned in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-intellisense?view=vs-2019#parameter-info). Another thing you can try is going to the definition (F12) and reading the XML comments.